# Do VLC 3.0 and above really play 7.1 audio?

Tags: vlc

I have a 7.1 speaker setup configured with my Ubuntu. I use VLC to play all type of media. Currently, VLC 3.0 is installed on my machine. It plays Dolby Atmos 7.1 and DTS-HD MA 7.1 very well. But I am not sure if VLC is really giving 7.1 output or if it just playing the core of Dolby Atmos 7.1 which is Dolby Digital 5.1 and same for DTS-HD MA 7.1 which DTS-HD MA 5.1.

The reason for this confusion is - if I play a 5.1 audio, I am still able to hear sound for all the 8(7.1) speaker. So, is VLC really giving output in 7.1 for a 7.1 audio?

Comment: Let me bring a case in point up:  Audio receivers for 5.1 surround sound, when they receive 2-channel, they kind of 'fudge' the 5.1 so that the surround sound system plays to all speakers, even though it's *not* actually a 5.1 signal.  2-channel audio for instance is still going to play through all 5 speakers in a standard setup, regardless of VLC or not, because sound cards usually handle that type of transcoding to some extent.  (2ch -> 5.1ch upwrite, same for 5.1ch -> 7.1ch)

Comment: I am not using AVR. Speakers are connected to PC directly. And by 7.1 sound, I meant 7.1 sound effect, different sound coming from different channels. For example, dialogues come from center speaker. So, basically want to understand that VLC really plays 7.1 audio with 7.1 effect or it just plays 5.1 sound?

Comment: I can't attest to your specific sound card, but unless your system's sound card actually *does* 7.1 correctly and runs that to 7 individual speaker channels plus the subwoofer, then it's unanswerable.  You might actually wish to ask the VLC developers how VLC handles 5.1 in a 7.1 environment or vice versa... just a thought.

Comment: My sound card does 7.1 correctly. Already tested with "speaker-test -Dplug:surround71 -c8". And my question is totally different. I want to know that if VLC actually play and output 7.1 audio or it just play the core of 7.1 audio which is 5.1 audio?

Comment: You could check this by downloading the test file from here: https://www.demolandia.net/cinema/dolby-demo-trailers-hd/page-8.html it has voiceover to test each speaker. This is 7.1 (not sure if it's Atmos though). You'll hear if there's mixing going on or if it's playing each channel correctly.

Comment: I downloaded 2 sample files - one with DTS-HD MA 7.1 and another one DTS-HD MA 5.1. VLC does play 7.1 audio with 7.1 effect. Also, VLC upmix 5.1 to 7.1. Amazing!! Thanks everyone.